# Rqaspberry run a java script on startup and see the cmd?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, startup, rc

I have a java code I want to run on startup , 
but I wnat to be able to see the code running on the CMD.(like when I run the java manually)

how do I do this ?

this is what I have in the rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address - this was in the default - didn't touch it..
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"

# run the java file from desktop
sudo java -jar Desktop/test.jar &
exit 0
```

Thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

From what i see, you have to option.

First you maybe need to wait a moment before the next command, witch is `exit 0` and will for sure exit, execute itself. Like this you will have time to read output.

Try to add `sleep 1m` befor `exit 0`
you will find more info on this command on google if you need, but 1m in exemple is for 1 minute

Other solution is to change a bit your java programm to wait for a user intput like for exemple:

```
System.out.println("\n Hit Return to exit... ");
String kS = scan.nextLine();
System.exit(0);
```

like this the java prog. will wait till you press return.

Hope you find what's best for you.

Comment: nope - still not working , to make thing simple I have this code :     import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        System.out.println("Hello - the device is UP and running now :-)");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String tmp = scanner.nextLine();

        System.exit(0);
    }

}          ------> still doesn't see him when I powerup the pi

Comment: Please Use the `code` balise to put your code in a good format. Then have you tried to add the ligne i told you at the end of your java code? whats the output when you run it on a console?

Comment: I have try , but he doesn't open the CMD - and show me nothing . I have added to the code to send me  a udp line and also upload a file using FTP.   both of them are working (so I know the code is OK). but I want to see it on screen